# Question about this smooth path

Tags: real-analysis

From my book, the definition of a smooth path is given as the image of a mapping $\gamma:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}^n$ such that the restriction $\gamma:(a,b) \to \mathbb{R}^n$ has a continuous bounded derivative such that $\gamma'(t) \neq 0$ for all parameter values in $(a,b)$.

As an example for myself, I said let's make $\gamma:[0,\pi] \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be the function $\gamma(t) = (t, cos(t))$.

My question is about what $\gamma'(t)$ means in the definition of smooth path above. Whenever I see the primes I tend to think of functions from $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ like in first semester analysis. I know that for my function I can construct the Jacobian matrix as

$D\gamma(t) = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -sin(t) \end{bmatrix}$.

I don't know how to match this with whatever $\gamma'(t)$ is. I know this may be very basic but I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What we have is a function from $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^n$. (Actually, the domain is just a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, but that's not too important.) When you have a function like that, you can think of it equivalently as a collection of functions $f_0,f_1,\ldots : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, which each $f_i$ giving the $i$th coordinate of $f$. Asking for $f$ to be smooth/continuous/differentiable/etc. is the same as asking that property of each of the individual $f_i$. Even further, if you want the $n$th derivative of $f$, i.e. $f^{(n)}$, that will be a function $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R^n}$ whose coordinates are giving by $f_0^{(n)},f_1^{(n)},\ldots$. In short, everything just works coordinate-by-coordinate.

Where things get more complicated is if the *domain* of the function is (a subset of) $\mathbb{R}^n$, instead of the range. That case is the topic of multivariable calculus. When it's just the *range* that's $\mathbb{R}^n$ (as it is in the case of a path), everything works as it does in ordinary single variable calculus, coordinate-by-coordinate.